# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

please help me . 
I have this error:

*An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The specified type member 'WebsiteUsersPersoana_Persoana_Id_wu' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*

This is my edmx:

[image]

And this is my database:

[image]

My problem is this: When admin tries to delete one website user, he must recieve a message with an alert=> You must to delete the person first.

He needs to know which person, so I need LINQ.

Here is the code:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var idPers = e.Values[0];


                var IdPers = Convert.ToInt16(idPers);

                var x = (from p in db.PersoanaSet
                         where p.WebsiteUsersPersoana_Persoana_Id_wu == IdPers
                         select p
                             ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


                litMsg.Text = "You need to delete this person:  "  +" " +  " "  + ex.Message;
            }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: **Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.** WebsiteUsersPersoana_Persoana_Id_wu isn't in that pic of your edmx.  Did you add it manually?  Nope.  Fix your edmx.

Comment: When I have created the model with entities and relationships, this database was auto-generated. So I did not add it manually.

Comment: Been a while since I linq'd to sql, but IIRC your edmx has to match everything you use.  Look at your edmx.  Look for that property you're referring to in your query.  It doesn't exist in the edmx.  Make it exist and try again, it may fix your problem.